# Dynamics AX: How to configure Archive Directory to use Sharepoint Online

Tags: sharepoint, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

We are getting error `Error during upload` when uploading a file that is configured to save files to SharePoint Online. This is on Microsoft Dynamics AX 2012 R3.

We have document management [enabled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamicsax-2012/appuser-itpro/configure-and-use-microsoft-dynamics-ax-document-management-with-microsoft-sharepoint-document-libraries), we are currently saving files to a local folder on the AOS server but now want to save files to our online sharepoint library in O365.

1. I created the following folder `AXTest` in sharepoint, and granted the AX service account access to the sharepoint team.

[image]

2. I set Archive directory appropriately. I tried various veresions of the URL, which were all unsuccessful:

   - https://xxxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/Dev-Test/AXTest
   - https://xxxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/Dev-Test/AXTest/Forms
   - various document folders

[image]

3. All result in error when trying to upload a file that is local to the AOS server:
   [image]
4. Through debugging, the error is raised here.

[image]

There is no exception stack so I don't know the exact reason why, but we tried various versions of the URL, we tried uploading a file locally, and we know the service account has access to the sharepoint site/team.  Any other ideas?

Comment: This might be an obvious question, but did you choose `SharePoint Online` for authentication type under document management parameters?

Comment: thanks @AlexKwitny, yes we had enabled that authentication type.

Comment: @Greg, did you resolve the problem?

Comment: @JanB.Kjeldsen, at the time, we deemed the original fixes not worth the effort (however we did not try the LCS fix mentioned by alex kwitny), so we are instead focusing our efforts on migrating to Dynamics365.

Answer (score 1):

Late but the "solution" is to make sure that a persistent cookie for SharePoint Online exists locally. I have been biting my head off to find a better solution, because it can get pretty complex to get that persistent cookie which makes it not suitable for end-users. To the point that my only solution might be to build a custom connector (or to urge for an upgrade...)

The key is to somehow force login.microsoftonline.com to prompt the user the question to remain signed-in. Only when you click Yes in that dialog is a persistent cookie created for SPO. Then the upload works fine, until the cookie expires / gets deleted.

These are the instructions for our users:

1. Make sure SPO / MS / Azure / ADFS related urls are not in the intranet zone in IE to prevent automatic login with windows credentials.

2. Sign out of SPO

3. Delete browser cookies

3. Restart IE

4. Go to SPO

5. You should be prompted to login with username and password

6. Then you will receive the question to Remain signed in. Click Yes.

Optional if this didnt work: Reset IE to default settings.

There's a KB included in CU13 for AX2012 R3 that seems to address the issue (mentions the vague "Error during upload" error). Haven't tested it myself, because i am trying to solve it in an AX2012 R2 CU9 environment.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran across the same issue and what a NIGHTMARE!

For Windows Server 2012 R2, I wrote this little PowerShell script to help clear the cookies for all users.

We had users sign out of AX, sign off the terminal server(s), and then I ran the below script to just remove all user cookies. Next connection, they were in business.

```
$Remove = $false

Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Users" -Directory | % {

    $CachePath = Join-Path -Path $_.FullName -ChildPath "\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCache"
    $CookiePath = Join-Path -Path $_.FullName -ChildPath "\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCookies"

    if (Test-Path -Path $CookiePath)
    {
        Write-Host $_.FullName -ForegroundColor Green

        if ($Remove) {
            Get-ChildItem -Path $CookiePath -File -Recurse | Remove-Item -Force -ErrorAction Continue
            Get-ChildItem -Path $CachePath -File -Recurse | Remove-Item -Force -ErrorAction Continue
        } else {
            Get-ChildItem -Path $CookiePath -File -Recurse | Format-Table -AutoSize
            Get-ChildItem -Path $CachePath -File -Recurse | Format-Table -AutoSize
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd like to note that when I posted this, I was unaware Microsoft Azure had a logon/authentication issue that was impacting me. This still worked but the real issue was Microsoft's servers.

Comment: Additional note, LCS hotfix `3842680` addresses this. Even after clearing cookies and getting things working, the issue may come back w/o the hotfix.